# Refresh button to call javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, refresh

In a page, I have a form and a JQGrid. The form is used to enter specific filters. So the Javascript for that page contains a function which reloads the data in order to populate the JQGrid. The JQGrid has `loadonce: true`, so the refresh button doesn't do anything. I would need to make it call my existing function. Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't post the code yet, because it's huge. I don't know how to delimitate what I should copy. Don't hesitate to ask for more infos.

Comment: Why not just set `loadonce: false`?

Comment: True. And it actually solved my issue. Thank you, you should write it down as an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple enough fix:

```
loadonce: false
```

really, setting this to true will serve no other purpose that you have specified.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly then your problem exist because `loadonce: true` option changes the original `datatype` (`"json"` or `"xml"`) to `"local"`. It allows to use local paging, sorting and filtering of data. During the paging, filtering and sorting the grid will be reloaded, so local reloading do have sense.

If you need to reload the grid from the server you should first restore the *original* value of `datatype` and then do reloading.

So if you can use `beforeRefresh` callback of `navGrid` to reset `datatype`:

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {
    beforeRefresh: function () {
        $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "json"});
    }
});
```

If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) then you can use new `fromServer: true` option of `reloadGrid` and you can use [new style of options](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods) and new `reloadGridOptions` option of `navGrid`. The code will be like

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    // standard jqGrid options
    navOptions: {
        // default options of navGrid
        reloadGridOptions: {fromServer: true}
    }
}).jqGrid("navGrid");
```

It will work with `datatype:"json"` or `datatype:"xml"`.